# IE presenting file download before request is complete

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, download, httpresponse

I'm attempting to present a file for download to the browser and I'm having a weird issue whereby Internet Explorer is presenting the file download to the user before the HTTP request is complete.

Here's my code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(pdfUrl);

    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-type", client.ResponseHeaders["content-type"]);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"]);
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

However, before the HTTP request is finished, the "Do you want to download this file" dialog at the bottom of the browser is being displayed.

This means that if the user clicks 'open' or 'download' before the HTTP request is complete, a corrupt or missing file is downloaded, resulting in an error.

I had thought that setting `Response.Buffer` and `Response.BufferOutput` to `true` would solve the issue, but forcing the response to wait until the request is complete before presenting the file to the browser, but this is not the case.

I suspect that the file is being presented for download before `Response.BinaryWrite` is complete.

**Edit**: The file opens/downloads perfectly fine if I wait for the HTTP request to finish before clickiing 'open/download'.

**Edit 2**: I've noticed that whilst the HTTP request is processing, IE doesn't have an idea of the content-type header; it only receives this once the request is complete. I don't think this is the issue, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, I think the prompting issue is just a red herring. Prompting to save before the file download is complete is completely normal. Imagine you were trying to download a 5GB file, do you really want to wait until the entire file is downloaded before you get a chance to say what to do with it?

Comment: The reason I'm reaching this conclusion is that the file opens perfectly fine if I wait until the HTTP request is complete, before clicking open.